# Exporting slide as an image not embedding fonts in Powerpoint VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins

I'm developing a powerpoint vsto addin and I'm trying to export a specific slide as an image using `Slide.Export` method, But the problem is, the `Export` method is not embedding fonts. The generated image always have system installed font. Below is the code snippet i'm using:

```
private void SaveSlideAsImage(Slide slide, string filePath, float w, float h)
{
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
        File.Delete(filePath);

    slide.Export(filePath, "jpg", (int)w, (int)h);
}
```

Can anyone help me how I can export a specific slide as image an which should have embedded font ?

**Update**
This is how the slide look like before export:
[image]

And this is how it look like after export. So you can see text is not matching and it could be because of embedded font
[image]

**Update 2:**
I have copied the only slide and then exported it. Now text is exported fine but now you can see font is different then the font in slide
[image]

and this is what i manually save and exported from powerpoint save as. Everything looks exact match of what's in slide:
[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear:  Images don't use fonts and cannot have fonts embedded. Is the problem that the text in exported images doesn't match the text on the original slide?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I have updated my question added screenshots of slides before export and after export. Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks. As a test, open the presentation in PPT, choose File | Save As, choose JPG and when asked, have it export just the current slide. Does the same problem occur?  Also, what happens if you re-create the problem text (NOT copy/paste ... re-create from start) in a new presentation?  I've seen situations where a slide or the text on it gets corrupted in some way that we can't see but that cause it to export badly.  If none of that sheds any light, can you post a presentation with just this slide in the cloud and give us a link to it?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Save As always works fine. The exported image has no issue. The issue occurs when i try to export the same slide using `Slide.Export` method in my VSTO plugin. I have updated the question again

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please also try re-creating the slide as I described above and exporting that via your code. If that works where the original slide doesn't, it's likely that the slide's content is corrupted.